# Is it actually possible to create a HTML5 game from scratch without any game frameworks, and have it run on the browser of any or most mobile devices?

Tags: html

please go easy on me when contributing to my question :)

Is it actually possible to create a HTML5 game from scratch without using any sort of game framework, and have it run on the browser of any or most mobile devices?

I have looked at many HTML5 game frameworks, Limejs and more, but I do not prefer to use a game framework of any kind.

For reasons that I prefer to have 100% control over my software without any rd party contribution integrated.

I just am curious whether a pure HTML5 html5, css and js project will be able to run on most or any user mobile devices, without getting into having to learning the Android or IOS frameworks.

I have previously been developing a game engine in pure Java with the more or less deprecated swing API, but I'm considering moving my efforts to HTML5 as I see alot of growth there.

I prefer to code everything from ground up. The game State, animation, collision, dialogue, every individual component such as I did with my Java swing game engine previously worked on.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes? I don't know what you're expecting us to say. You can create a game using only html nodes , you can create a game using canvas , you can create a game using webGL ( Might have forgotten something) . What path do you wish to take?

Comment: If there are third party libraries that do what you want but don't want to use them, *simply* (tongue deep in cheek) implement the functionality yourself.

Comment: Thanks Paran0a, To do so Using the new HTML5 Canvas element  I believe. so yes, It is indeed possible?, If I understood that correctly thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.
 I've done a few html5, all have been done without the use of any framework.
its actually easier to develop games from scratch in html5 than it is in other programming languages, because you have certain features: like canvas, creating images, drawing arc, font manipulation.
 
In other languages, like C/C++, pascal etc.  graphic/animation/ or video primitives are not part of the language, so you would have to either build the library or use a 3rd party library.
 
Not the case with HTML5. a lot of the tools needed to make games are part of html5.